# Ag-grid css styles not working in firefox

Tags: css, ag-grid

I am trying to change style for spesific column in ag-grid using either cellStyle- or cellClassRules-property.

css is located in css-file:

```
.align-content-to-end {
    text-align: end;
    .ag-input-field-input {
      text-align: end;
    };
}
```

This works well in Chrome. In firefox I get following (Invalid property name)
[image]

What is my problem?

Comment: this is not CSS code, that's SCSS/SASS. you need to either compile your SCSS to CSS or just write plain CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Started using scss/sass. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid CSS. That's valid SCSS or Sass syntax but you can't do that with normal CSS. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but either use Sass or SCSS or do what the other person said

Answer (score 1):

so use `text-align: right;` instead of 'end'

```
.align-content-to-end {
    text-align: right;
    .ag-input-field-input {
      text-align: right;
    };
}
```

also you are using SASS syntax in CSS which will not work!
simply do this instead

```
.align-content-to-end {
    text-align: right;
}
.ag-input-field-input {
    text-align: right;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Started using scss/sass.

Comment: happy to help :) also you can mark as an answer